# Checking if class name is valid in Java

Tags: java, class

I would like to check if class name is valid at the compile time. I can certainly import the class and get a compilation error, however what I want is to be able to catch this error. How can I do that, if that's not a good way what other alternatives can I do that?

For example

```
import com.foo.classname;

public class Foo {
 public String classProperties() {
  if(classname) {//this is when class is found
   ClassName className = new ClassName();
   return className.toString();
  }
  else {//this is when class is not found
   return getOtherProperty();
  }

 }


}
```

Please don't post anything runtime such as `Class.forName` solutions.

Edit: After getting so many negative feedback. I would like to explain a little more about my idea.

My main motivation ideas were:

1) I have seen some code which are using Reflection for this. Such as loading a library from JDK 7 and using that library methods to initialise a String, also writing something else(probably less efficient) to catch block where exception is occurred. I wanted to avoid this situation

2) Both errors and warnings are created by the compiler. If we can suppress a warning, then I thought it was possible to suppress an error.

Comment: Class name valid <=> code compiles with appropriate import

Comment: I know, but as I said, what should I do when it is invalid? Then code won't compile, however I want it to compile and would like to handle this.

Comment: Import the class if it exists or create the class if it doesn't? You should explain what you are trying to achieve because your questions don't make much sense...

Comment: This makes no sense.  You want it to compile - that is, the error is not detected at compile time.  And you don't want to detect it at runtime.  When would you LIKE to detect it?

Comment: If you want to do this in Java, you're going to need to write a Java program to do it -- which does mean using runtime solutions in _that_ program -- so I'm really not sure what you're asking. Unless it's simply a tool to parse the compiler's error output?

Comment: "Please don't post anything runtime such as Class.forName solutions."  You are asking for a Class.forName solution.

Comment: I want the error to be detected at the compile time.
However, I still want my program to be compiled. What I am looking for is to suppress the error, and then somehow be able to find whether this error has occurred or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the impossible.

Comment: @HotLicks, I wanted to know whether is there a way to do or not, because I know that we can suppress a warning, so I thought we can suppress errors too.

Comment: You can't suppress an error. An error means there is no reasonable guess or interpretation that can be made about your intent.

Comment: Some IDEs can warn you that a referenced class is undefined during editing. They generally do so by using runtime operations such as Class.forName and reflection. If you were coding such an IDE in something other than Java, you'd need to write equivalent classpath-searching logic.

Comment: So, even if your compiler could fabricate a class whenever you refer to one that doesn't exist, how would it know what return type to use for calls to methods of that class?

Answer (score 2):

To get compile errors like this you would have to work at the compiler level, either you write your own compiler or use something like JavaCC or Javassist.

Cheers